# How do I use emission, without my object's shape getting lost in the emission?

Tags: emission

Not sure if that was the best way to describe it, but I am trying to use emission on a certain object shape but I still want to be able to see the objects shape. I am assuming because the emission is all the same brightness and color, that this is why I can't see the objects shape.
Is there a certain node set up or process I can do besides manually changing several planes to a different emission or material?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You could try with Ambient Occlusion and a color ramp.

[image]

Comment: And in Eevee he must not forget to activate the Ambient Occlusion option in the Render panel